# VLOOKUP two different items, use whichever one has a number

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have a list of financial metrics in column A, rest of the columns are the time periods the financial data is for.

Let's say I'm trying to calculate a ratio, but the financial metrics in A are not entirely unique, in the sense that a metric type may have more than one associated metric depending on how the company reports the metric.

For example, let's say I need Depreciation Expense on the income statement... that item may be reported as Depreciation, or DepreciationAndAmortization, or something else.

Any ideas how the formula in the ratio I'm trying to calculate can lookup the metric in A1, use the number immediately to the right as part of the formula... and if the metric Depreciation for example is 0, it would look for the next one I specify, like DepreciationAndAmortization, and use that one instead as the first one isn't reported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this should do it:

```
=MAX(INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*depreciation*",A:A,)),INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*depreciation*",A:A,)+MATCH("*depreciation*",INDEX(A:A,1+MATCH("*depreciation*",A:A,)):INDEX(A:A,100+MATCH("*depreciation*",A:A,)),)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much man! Seems to work just fine :) can i please ask you how I can keep the A:A column fixed? so when I drag the ratio formula to calculate the ratio for the other columns, Excel knows to search only the A column? Thanks!

Comment: Also can i ask what the 1+MATCH and the 100+Match means?

Comment: You are welcome! To fix the A column, just change the `A:A` references to this: `$A:$A`  That's it,

Comment: The `+1` is a way to tell it to start looking at the next row after the first find. The `+100` tells it to scan up to 100 rows past the first find in order to get the next find. You can adjust that `+100` to scan further if you need it to.

Comment: On the MAX function, if one of the items found in VLOOKUP doesn't have an integer (let's say there's an error string because the data isn't available), while the other item using VLOOKUP has a number..... Excel returns #VALUE error because one of the items has a string and it won't display the higher number (as I would prefer).... any ideas? thanks

Comment: It's not clear what you mean... especially since we are not using VLOOKUP at all. But please email me a sample workbook that shows the problem and I'll take a look. My email address is:  daniel.ferry@gmail.com

Comment: If you still need help, please send me the file.

Answer (score 0):

If the alternatives are say in E2 and E3 then:

```
=MAX(VLOOKUP(E2,A:B,2,0),VLOOKUP(E3,A:B,2,0))
```

ie try both and take whichever is larger.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

About your concern on the answer of Excel Hero that returns Value error, you can use the function "iferror" and returns "0" if the value/date you're looking for isn't available.

```
       =IFERROR(MAX(INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*depreciation*",$A:$A,)),INDEX(B:B,MATCH("*depreciation*",$A:$A,)+MATCH("*depreciation*",INDEX($A:$A,1+MATCH("*depreciation*",$A:$A,)):INDEX($A:$A,100+MATCH("*depreciation*",$A:$A,)),))),0)
```